# Swiffy HTML5 file size

Tags: google-swiffy

What am i doing wrong with the conversion of a 30k swf file and it being converted through the Swiffy extension in Flash CS5 to a 137k HTML5 file? It's a simple banner ad and the requirements for distribution are under 75k. Please, anyone that can shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

this is because of the runtime.js file added by swiffy (its massive) - depending on where you're serving the ad from, you can just link to an external source and not include it in your zip

Eg - Adwords wont let you do that, but doubleclick should.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see if you are allowed to count the banner file size based on the zipped size. When you zip up a Swiffy banner, the file size is usually only 5KB larger than the SWF. I have gotten all of my Swiffy converted banners trafficked no problem. If it is for Sizmek, it will be counting the unzipped size, so you may need to heavily compress images to get the banner under 200KB or 150KB. If it is for DCM or DCS, then 100KB zipped size will be more than enough for your banner.